# Why does Ubuntu's `venv` require installing `python3-venv`?

Tags: package-management, python3

[`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/venv.html#module-venv) is a standard python3 module, thus I assume it should be shipped with python3 by default.
That is not quite true on Ubuntu 16.04: to use `venv` you also need to install `python3-venv`.
**Why on Ubuntu `venv` is split into `venv` and `python3-venv`?**

Comment: I can run `venv` without installing python3-venv in 16.04

Comment: I am able to run `python3 -m venv --help` without installing `python3-venv`, and so did a few other users in the chatroom. Are you sure you need to install `python3-venv`?

Comment: @edwinksl @Anwar I guess that is because you have pip3 installed (?). I had a fresh ubuntu without pip/pip3 and it complained just like here: https://askubuntu.com/q/760177/41363. I tried option `--without-pip`, it created the environment but could not activate it (as far as i remember). Then I installed package `python3-env`, and it works now (though I still don't have `pip` system-wide installed).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ensurepip is disabled in Debian/Ubuntu for the system python](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879437/ensurepip-is-disabled-in-debian-ubuntu-for-the-system-python)